# Mongo Motor Client AllowDiskUse

Tags: mongodb, fastapi, motordriver

I am currently using the Motor client (v3.1.1) in a FastAPI application. When attempting to implement pagination, the following code works fine:

```
client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient('mongodb://<my-connection-string>/')
database = client.test_database
collection = database.test_collection
pipeline = [
    { "$facet": 
        {"items": 
            [{ "$match": { }},
            {"$sort": {"_id": -1}},
            { "$skip": pageskip },
            { "$limit": pagesize },
            ],
        "totalCount": [{ "$count": "count" }]}}
        ]

cursor = collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

However after a certain number of pages I get the following error:

```
raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but 
did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt 
in., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 
bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass 
allowDiskUse:true to opt in.', 'code': 292, 
'codeName':'QueryExceededMemoryLimitNoDiskUseAllowed'}
```

I tried using [allowDiskUse][1] directly in aggregation but then I get the following:

```
raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'allowDiskUse', 
full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'allowDiskUse'", 
'code': 40324, 'codeName': 'Location40324'}
```

Thanks in advance if anyone knows how to implement [allowDiskUse](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.allowDiskUse/) with the Motor client ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add it as flag to your `aggregate` method:

```
cursor = collection.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)
```

Comment: I guess, it must be a JSON object, i.e. `cursor = collection.aggregate(pipeline, { allowDiskUse: true} )` It may depend on the programming language.

Comment: he said fastapi, so I assume it is python